# Total Physical Ram not showing full ram installed

Tags: windows-7, memory

I just upgraded my RAM from 4gb to 8gb.  My mother states he can be handled up to 16gb.  I installed 4x2gb memory.

When I boot up and look into the system information file on my windows 7 machine it states

Installed Physical Memory = 8gb
Available Physical Memory = 2.75GB

Any help on this would be help

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using a 32 bit OS. You must use 64 bit OS to get full 8 GB. Given condition your CPU must support 64 bit OS

Comment: This is not true in general, but is true specifically for Windows these days. PAE allows accessing more than 4 GB on a 32-bit operating system, and this is supported by e.g. Linux. But the OP is asking about Windows, and 32-bit Windows no longer supports PAE to access more than 4 GB.

Comment: thanks, how would I make the change to allow 32bit OS to use all 8 gb

Comment: @mike, you cannot, unless you install a 64bit windows OS. before you do so however, confirm that your CPU can run a 64bit system (its pretty much certain that it can, but better safe than sorry).

Comment: I've got http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-Athlon%20II%20X2%20240%20-%20ADX240OCK23GQ%20(ADX240OCGQBOX).html